# Extract all inline css of concernet html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-parsing, html-content-extraction

I want to extract all inline styles of the concerned html.

For example, below is the concerned html for which inline css is to be extracted:

```
<div id="concernedHtmlPortion" style="style1">
    <div style="style2">
    <div style="style3;style4">Hello World!!</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to extract all `style` by using only root `id="concernedHtmlPortion"`?

Result of extraction should be: `style1,style2,style3,style4`

Any help please !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allStyles = [];
$('#concernedHtmlPortion, #concernedHtmlPortion [style]').each(function() {
    allStyles.push($(this).attr('style').split(';'));
});
alert(allStyles);​
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/svjWw/3)
​

Comment: Doesn't quite work as requested... the styles aren't split when there are multiple by `;` and you missed the style from the containing #concernedHtmlPortion element. Seems you too, are capable of misreading the question! =)

Comment: Thanks! this is what i wanted. Although I have done using childnode concept but your provided code is better than mine.

Comment: yeah. i accepted the answer. thanks to tell me! next time i will remember that.

Comment: @user966709. You can still accept answers for your old questions. There is no time limitation. Good luck!